# How to execute a sql query in jscript/jscript.NET

Tags: sql, jscript, jscript.net

First at all sorry for my English, this is not my native language. So.

I want to execute a SQL query in a script to get some data. I don't know if it's possible and if so, how to make it. To summarize :

- The script add a button in M3 Smart Office (a ERP). I already done that.
- When i select a row in a M3 function (like an article, or a client) i want to take and send his ID (and some other data) to a website.

They're is a lot of function in M3. In each function, they're are some field who contains a data. One of them contain the ID of the object (An article, a client,...). What i want to do, is to get this ID. The problem is that the field who contains the ID doesn't have the same name in all the function. So, i have two solutions :

- Do a lot of if/elseif. Like "if it's such function, take such field". But if I (or somebody else) want to add a combination function/field later i (or somebody else ;) )need to do that in the script. It's not practical.
- Create a sql table wich contain all the combination function/field. Then is the script, i do a sql query and i get all the data that the script need.

So here the situation. Maybe you have ideas to do that otherwise (without sql) and i take it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this in depth tutorial from the 4guysfromrolla site:

[Server-Side JScript Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20181223085132/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/061800-1.shtml)